# Xcode code completion: filtering to show only direct API methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete, xcode7

I have lots of troubles with Xcode code completion.

When I just want to use it to "browse" the available properties and methods of an object, I immediately have lots of not-so-useful information like all the elements inherited from `NSObject`, methods from the `UIAccessibilityAction` protocol, ...

As soon as I type some letters for a method or property, I quickly find what I need and continue to code, but sometimes I do not even know the first letter of my method or property.

I would like to just display what was created in the `@interface` of the object I want to auto-complete.

Is it possible to filter a little more what is displayed the code completion popup ? I do not want a mechanism to jump to the interface declaration, it is really for quick coding.

Comment: Autocompletion is a good and efficient work aid. It is, however, not remotely a suitable substiture for actually learning the API.